# 0.0.0.0 foreign adress LISTENING at loopback

Tags: networking, ip

I used netstat and found some app LISTENING at loopback with foreign adress at 0.0.0.0

Does this mean that some app potentially a rootkit?

Thank you

```
NAME    LOCAL ADRESS        FOREIGN ADRESS          STATE        PID
TCP     127.0.0.1:27015     0.0.0.0:0               LISTENING    6796
```

[image: Apple root kit mobile service]

Comment: best to show output of what you speak of, eg paste from termnal

Comment: @barlop I have updated the question with example of output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a 0.0.0.0 foreign address means nobody has connected <-- You have this.

a 0.0.0.0 local address means listening on all interfaces.  <-- You don't have this.

a 127.0.0.1 local address means listening only on 127.0.0.1 which means only your computer can connect. <-- You have this.  I'd think that's pretty harmless really. Even listening on 0.0.0.0 can be OK when you have a firewall..(+NAT router helps), but yours is way safer than that.  Even another computer on your LAN would not be able to connect, let alone from the Internet!

LISTENING rather than ESTABLISHED,  so it means nobody is connected.

All LISTENING connections have foreign address of 0.0.0.0  and I think probably vice versa too, all foreign addresses of 0.0.0.0 are listed as LISTENING. So it makes sense that you have LISTENING and a foreign address of 0.0.0.0  That's normal.

In your case,  your foreign address is 0.0.0.0, so nobody has connected

And in your case,  since the IP for local address 127.0.0.1  as opposed to a LAN IP or 0.0.0.0, it means that only 127.0.0.1 is allowed to connect.  If it were a LAN Address  it means anybody from your LAN can coonnect, and if it was 0.0.0.0 then it means anybody can connect.

A local IP of 127.0.0.1 LISTENING is typically the least concern 'cos only your local computer can connect to it(your computer connecting to itself)!  Like a client and server running.. And that's when ESTABLISHED.

A local IP of 0.0.0.0  LISTENING can be more of a security concern but can be OK.  But you'd then want to look at if the foreign address is from the Internet, and then what the PID is. And consider whether you want foreign addresses from the Internet connecting or if you want to block them with your firewall, and they'd have to get past your NAT router too, But this is not your situation. As your server or service is listening on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Thank you very much. But is it possible, that Apple made a sniffer for advertising purposes?

Comment: @kitscribe if they did then i'm not gonna be the guy that catches it!!

Answer (score 0):

"0.0.0.0" means, that a server is listening on every available interface with the corresponding IP. This has nothing to do with a root kit but you probably wanna check it either way, maybe some game wants to let players join via lan, or it's the windows netbios. If you want help with identifying it, please comment the port number.

Comment: With PID I had identify it as an itunes service. So I just wanted to be sure before ask any questions to Apple

Comment: So that's it? I mean you wanted to find out what it is...? If yes, please tag my answer as solved :)

Comment: are you sure about this.. he has foreign address as 0.0.0.0 not local address

Comment: I think you're  probably wrong on this

Comment: Sorry, my bad...